# Unable to set value using useState()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set value that is being imported from another function. But when I try to set it using `useState()` it returns `empty array`.

Code:

```
function something() {
    const(dataDetails,setDataDetails) = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        async function fetchDataValue() {
            api call using axios => fetched data
            setMailDataList(data)
        }
        fetchDataValue()
    }, [data])
    
    return(
        <ShowValue dataValue={dataDetails} />
    )
}
```

another page where I'm trying to import the value:

```
function anotherfunction(props) {
   console.log(props.dataValue) // while doing this it prints the value

   const(newData,setNewData) = useState(props.dataValue)

   console.log(newData)   // this give me empty array 
}
```

So It's giving me empty array when trying to set value using useState.
As I need setNewData to update the value of newData for further use so I need it in this form.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You're adding 'data' to the array in useEffect. Where does this come from? What happens if you remove 'data', and just leave an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure your code follow this format.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return <SomeComponent name="Hello" />;
}

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  console.log("props.name", props.name);
  const [newState, setNewState] = useState(props.name);
  console.log("newState", newState);

  return null;
};
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-bush-dejkv?file=/src/App.js:0-306)

As you can see from codesandbox, the console is correct.

Comment: function anotherfunction(props) {
   console.log(props.dataValue) // while doing this it prints the value

   const(newData,setNewData) = useState(props.dataValue)

   console.log(newData)   // this give me empty array 
}

here in console.log(props.dataValue) it is giving the required data fetched
but only after I do this:
const(newData,setNewData) = useState(props.dataValue) OR const newData = props.dataValue
and print the newData then only it is giving me empty array.
So data have been fetched in props.dataValue but after I try to set it to some new variable it is gibing empty

Comment: u need to use square bracket, not round bracket.

Comment: square bracket in which part? This one?
const(newData,setNewData) = useState(props.dataValue)

to 

const(newData,setNewData) = useState([props.dataValue])??

Comment: Sorry it was error from my part I have used square bracket only in my actual code. By mistake I used round bracket over here. So my problem is same that I have mentioned

Comment: Give me few minutes at first glance it looks the same...but if there is something I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be square brackets. Instead of

```js
const(newData,setNewData) = useState(props.dataValue)
```

it should be

```js
const[newData,setNewData] = useState(props.dataValue)
```